# how to get the size of a file presented as channelBuffer

Tags: java, netty

Need to look at the size of a file passed in as ChannelBuffer.

Should I use limit() or capacity? is it accurate to the real size?

Answer (score 0):

You can use capacity -1 (as it is 0-based) to get the number of bytes in the channelBuffer.

```
 ChannelBuffer buffer = ...;
 a = buffer.capacity() - 1;
```